# How to get control from email app to calling activity

Tags: android, email-client

I had a scenario where I need to send email from my android app.

```
           String to = textTo.getText().toString();
          String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
          String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

          Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

          //need this to prompts email client only
          email.setType("message/rfc822");

          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

I used the above code which opens up gmail app and I sent the mail. 
 
But is there a way in which can we track from our app like from calling activity or fragment whether the mail is sent or not so that I need to make some UI updates in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, this is not part of the API. It returns once you have pressed send button even if it is not sent.

Answer (score 0):

Since the intent starts another app it is in these other apps responsibility to return some kind of information wether the mail was sent or not - and I don't know any Mail app that actually does that. And if there would be one, not everyone will use it.
So the only way to make sure you get the info is by using your own Mailserver and [AndroidMail](https://github.com/enrichman/androidmail). This way you send the mail directly from your app and not assign the task to other apps like you do with `Intent.ACTION_SEND`